# OpenCV, PyCharm - нет отображения видео

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

Код обрабатывает и записывает видео:

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import os
import urllib

def drawRectangle(frame, bbox):
    p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
    p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
    cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255, 0, 0), 2, 1)


def displayRectangle(frame, bbox):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    frameCopy = frame.copy()
    drawRectangle(frameCopy, bbox)
    frameCopy = cv2.cvtColor(frameCopy, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    plt.imshow(frameCopy)
    plt.show()


def drawText(frame, txt, location, color=(50, 170, 50)):
    cv2.putText(frame, txt, location, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, color, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  video_input_file_name = "race_car.mp4"
  tracker = cv2.legacy_TrackerBoosting.create()
  video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_input_file_name)
  ok, frame = video.read()

  if not video.isOpened():
        print("Could not open video")
        sys.exit()
  else:
        width = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        height = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

        video_output_file_name = 'race_car-' + tracker_type + '.mp4'
        video_out = v2.VideoWriter(video_output_file_name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 25, (width, height))

        bbox = (1300, 405, 160, 120)
        displayRectangle(frame, bbox)
        ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

        while True:
            ok, frame = video.read()
            if not ok:
                break

            timer = cv2.getTickCount()
            ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)
            fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

            if ok:
                drawRectangle(frame, bbox)
            else:
                drawText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (80, 140), (0, 0, 255))

            drawText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (80, 60))
            drawText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (80, 100))

            video_out.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame) # no video

    video.release()
    video_out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

записанный видеофайл - без нареканий
Но если добавить строчку, чтобы это видео также отображалось на экране - отображения не происходит.
Что мешает отображению видео?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С логикой проблемы. Вы с камеры пишите?

Comment: displayRectangle что такое? И вообще покажите все импорты, так как в текущем состоянии ваш скрипт не работает.

Comment: Здравствуйте Александр, спасибо, что обратили внимание на мой вопрос. Пример кода поправил, добавил не указанные ранее импорты и функции. Используемый видео-файл здесь: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17-323N16kO8NeHyApgCG-dHmHtdiXbu6/view?usp=sharing
Сейчас читаю с файла, в дальнейшем планирую читать с камеры.
Суть кода в том, что присходит чтение видео из файла, на первом кадре прямоугольником отмечается тот объект, который надо отслеживать (сопровождать) - это движущийся автомобиль, он помечается синим прямоугольником и итоговое видео (с авто в прямоугольной рамке) записывается в файл.

Comment: Записанный итоговый файл, выглядит вот так: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCZp2EsCdTTDMllgnLG1bPW3qqq9GgOl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hk-pokRfivsyWHWBjQaXgKxJIunVbAXr/view?usp=sharing
поправил - исходный файл здесь

Answer (score 0):

Сколько ведь раз говорено... RTFM!

надо все-таки в первую очередь читать документацию, а там для метода imshow()
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. imshow() всегда ожидает следующий за ним call to cv::waitKey or cv::pollKey

поэтому для отображения, необходимо написать:

```
video_out.write(frame)
cv2.imshow("Tracker", frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1)
```

поскольку пишется 25 кадров в секунду (1000 : 25 = 40 мС <== на каждый фрейм), то ожидание waitKey() 1 мС никак не мешает ни записи, ни отображению